# logic to display an image on clicking a comment(link) using Ajax

Tags: ajax

What is the logic to display an image by clicking on any comment link(like when we click on photo1 it should be display the image of photo1 other times the image should be hidden)...(using javascript)

Comment: You're going to have to provide more details than that. Is the image already on the page and you are just showing/hiding, or do you need  ajax to retrieve it? Are you retrieving the image or the path to the image? What does your current code look like?

Answer (score 0):

check the below example, Mouseover an image thumbnail to get a pop-up preview @

Answer (score -1):

Try with this

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

       function openWin(img){

           var path = "images/"

           window.open(path+img,"mywin","menubar=0,resizable=0,width=200,height=200")
                            }
    </script>
    <title>Open Window</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="javascript:openWin('image0.png')">open window</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The image should be opened in the same window